# Power BI calcualte the variance between two rows of table data

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, m

first time caller long time listener.  I'm trying to work out the variance for each row of a table of data for my local junior tiathlon club.  I need to work out the difference of time in a particular event since the previous date to know if they have improved or not. e.g. if a student only runs for two days and these are recorded as rows, how can i add a column to calculate if they are faster or slower?   The data is below and the final column illustrates what i need.  You'll see that the variance resets to 0 for each category.  I'm trying to do this in Power BI DEsktop in the tables as an added column so i can use the data against a matrix table report.

Put simply, how can i measure the time in the current row against the time in the previous row>

Thanks in advance, Moe

[image]

Comment: Hello, would you mind putting your sample data in a markdown format so that it can be easily copy/pasted by answerers?

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/earlier-function-dax

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
// might need to replace replace Excel.CurrentWorkbook with Excel.WorkBook for Power BI
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Event", type text}, {"Category", type any}, {"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Name", "Event"}, {
    {"data", each
    let a=Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.Sort(_,{{"Date", Order.Ascending}, {"Time", Order.Ascending}}), "index", 0, 1, Int64.Type) ,
    b=Table.AddColumn(a,"diff", each try  Duration.ToText(a{[index]}[Time] - a{[index]-1}[Time]) otherwise 0) 
  in b, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Category", "Date", "Time", "diff"}, {"Category", "Date", "Time", "diff"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data",{{"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}})
in #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]